# Tabla HTML COLSPAN 1.5

Tags: html, css

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```html
<table border="1">
        <tr style="height: 50px;">
            <th style="text-align: left;width: 15%;">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d1/Dian_%28Colombia%29_logo.svg/2560px-Dian_%28Colombia%29_logo.svg.png" style="width: 200px;">
            </th>
            <th style="width: 70%;">
                <label style="">Certificado de Ingresos y Retenciones por Rentas de Trabajo y de Pensiones <br>
                Ano gravable 2022</label>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 15%;">
                <img src="220.png" style="width: 200px;">
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Antes de diligenciar este formulario lea cuidadosamente las instrucciones</th>
            <th>4. Numero de formulario</th>
        </tr>
        

    </table>
```

La cual se ve de la siguiente forma:

[image: Imagen1]

pero quiero que se vea así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es como tener un `colspan` de 1.5 la verdad no sé cómo realizarlo

Comment: no se puede 1.5, puedes digamos multiplicar x2 y asignarle a todo colspan pero no es lo ideal, para este tipo de casos lo ideal es usar `display: 'grid'` o `display: 'flex'`

Comment: Estás haciéndolo web o usas alguna librería de PDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeramente, como recomendación, utiliza la estructura completa de una tabla, como lo son las etiquetas `thead` y `tbody`.

Ahora con tu duda, puedes considerar que al usar el atributo `colspan`, deberías tener definida una longitud en tu cabecera, para que en el cuerpo de la tabla puedas tener medidas proporcionales, te muestro este ejemplo basado en el tuyo:

```html
  <table border="1" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="4"><img
            src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d1/Dian_%28Colombia%29_logo.svg/2560px-Dian_%28Colombia%29_logo.svg.png"
            style="width: 200px;"></th>
        <th colspan="4"><label>Certificado de Ingresos y Retenciones por Rentas de Trabajo y de Pensiones <br>
            A&ntilde;o gravable 2022</label></th>
        <th colspan="4"><img
            src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d1/Dian_%28Colombia%29_logo.svg/2560px-Dian_%28Colombia%29_logo.svg.png"
            style="width: 200px;"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="6">Antes de diligenciar este formulario lea cuidadosamente las instrucciones</td>
        <td colspan="6">4. Numero de formulario</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

En este caso definí que la sumatoria del colspan de la cabecera `th` sea de 12, para así poder darle un valor de 6 en el cuerpo `td`.